# Responder o que está na pergunta? e prever o futuro!

Tags: debate

Respondi o [questionamento de um usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157317/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-ordenar-o-resultado-do-model-pai-pelo-model-filho), e acabei resolvendo o item de ordenação, após isso o usuário disse que a ordenação não começava com zero e o mesmo estava fazendo operações com a `$key` do seu `foreach`, e respondi que eu não sabia qual operação estava fazendo com o `foreach` e que a informação não estava na questão, observe abaixo imagem em anexo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Talvez por esse comentário da minha parte o usuário não gostou da forma como eu disse, mas, depois veio dizendo:

- Há que frescura!
- Que politica é essa!

**Pergunto:**

O objetivo principal, não é responder aquilo que o usuário postou na sua pergunta, ressalvas algum duvida relacionado a pergunta?

Qual é maneira correta de se portar numa ocasião como essa?

Comment: Virgílio, tenho que trazer isso aqui:  Esse usuário fala dessa maneira mesmo. Agora não sei se é grosseria ou é o jeito mesmo dele falar. O último comentário ele está agradecendo com um "Obrigado", então sempre é melhor pensar o bem e não o mal.

Comment: Vou analisar isso com cuidado assim que der, mas já adianto que tem alguns usuários que não postam perguntas claras e acham que a culpa é de quem está respondendo de não entender. Pior ainda quando a pessoa começa mudar os requisitos no meio do processo transformando em [pergunta X Y](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/101).

Comment: Pra variar, essa pergunta, tenho quase certeza, é duplicada.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu quero entender os procedimentos, eu quero aprender, e isso leva um tempo aqui, acredito eu, mas, eu achei ele grosseiro de certo modo.

Comment: Galera desculpa, não sabia que já tinha uma questão assim. Mas vale para mim também como experiência.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não é a primeira pessoa que reclama desse usuário, mas eu não vou colocar isso em questão aqui. Vou deixar isso para os moderadores. Caso sinta que algum comentário seja ofensivo, use o recurso da sinalização, que serão avaliados pelos moderadores.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não precisa pedir desculpas. Perguntas duplicadas são boas, elas linkam as outras.

Comment: Obrigado pela Analise @bigown, quero entender!

Comment: Obrigado também @WallaceMaxters pelos seus comentários. quem puder também estou aberto a ler !!!

Comment: Por bem menos vieram aqui me chamar de "mal educado" e dizer que eu estava praticando moderação agressiva. Espero que a moderação analise o caso com cuidado, senão pode parecer 2 pesos, 2 medidas.

Comment: @diegofm só dizendo que se tratando de moderadores diferentes pode ocorrer dois pesos e duas medidas :), o que era mais urgente já foi feito e o tema está sendo debatido pelos moderadores

Comment: Não gostei do título dessa pergunta. Achei sarcástica.

Comment: Prever o futuro, parece que esse é um skill necessário na nossa carreira hsuashaush

Comment: Quando respondo a um usuário - através de algum comentário - e o mesmo vem com grosseria e desrespeito, me silencio, encerro o diálogo e sinalizo o referido comentário para uma possível análise da moderação. Pois, nesses casos, não adianta continuar com o diálogo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creio que dois procedimentos podem ser aplicados em tais casos onde o *usuário te enche de perguntas nos comentários, sendo que ele não descreveu isso na pergunta, e você já respondeu*:

- Pedir ao usuário que faça uma edição na pergunta, descrevendo os problemas que ele "esqueceu" de colocar na pergunta, e, ao mesmo tempo, se comprometer em editar a resposta.
- Pedir ao usuário para fazer uma nova pergunta.

Desses dois casos, eu prefiro o segundo, pois é o menos problemático. Pois, no primeiro caso, se o usuário editar a pergunta e outras respostas além da sua já estiverem publicadas, as respostas também teriam que ser editadas. E nesse caso, quem respondeu não tem culpa de o AP ter esquecido de ter colocado isso na pergunta. Além do mais, dependendo do nível de questionamento do usuário, ele pode alterar todo o contexto da pergunta, invalidando a pergunta e sua resposta (e as demais, se existirem). É claro que nós temos uma maneira de reverter a edição, mas em todo caso, veja o tanto de problema que isso poderia causar. Então, eu trataria o primeiro caso com extremo bom-senso. O segundo item é mais fácil.

Se você observar, na pergunta que nós dois respondemos, eu fiz exatamente como o segundo item: Pedi para formular uma nova pergunta.

[Propriedade do objeto vindo do JSON não está acessivel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157727/propriedade-do-objeto-vindo-do-json-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-acessivel/157733)

## Concluíndo

> Alguém está usando o comentário para fazer várias questionamentos que não foram pedidas na pergunta?

Peça para ele fazer uma nova pergunta. É a opção mais fácil. Além do quê, tem coisas que não dá pra explicar nos comentários.

Lembrando que, se os comentários se estenderem, você pode usar o chat para auxiliar o AP. Já houve casos onde eu ajudei um rapaz a resolver o problema assim (e cheguei a conclusão que o que eu fiz para ajudar ele não tinha nada a ver com o que foi perguntando).

> O usuário foi rude ou ofensivo comigo, gratuitamente

Você pode usar o recurso de sinalização de comentários. A moderação do Stackoverflow é bem competente. Se for constatado que o usuário está querendo fazer intrigas, eles vão resolver.

<sub>Não estou puxando saco, já recebi pelo menos três punições no chat, por intervenção da moderação (e creio que a maioria foi justa).</sub>

É claro que sempre é bom lembrar o usuário pode estar se expressando naturalmente. Algumas pessoas podem parecer doces ou amargas nos comentários, mas é sempre bom supor à boa intenção.

Temos que lembrar que o Stackoverflow "atende" várias regiões do país, e as vezes eu me preocupo se a expressão de alguém, que para mim é ofensiva, para o outro possa ser natural.

É difícil afirmar se o usuário nesse caso foi rude com você ou não, pois ele diz "que frescura", mas em seguida diz "obrigado".

Isso aí eu já não vou entrar, deixa com a moderação :p

Comment: A única diferença é que nesse caso o rapaz foi educado, nada rude, mas, o resto de **pedir uma nova pergunta** eu também concordo.

Comment: É como eu disse: *O usuário pode estar se expressando naturalmente*. Algumas pessoas já chegaram a pensar que eu estava "tirando" elas nos comentários. Mas na verdade me expliquei depois que é meu costume falar assim. Temos que lembrar que o Stackoverflow "atende" várias regiões do país, e as vezes eu me preocupo se a expressão que para mim é ofensiva para o outro possa ser natural.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acho que pedir uma nova pergunta "sai mais em conta". Editar pareceu muito burocrático só de pensar...

Comment: E nos casos de como eu ja tiverem esta nova pergunta e ainda sim elas não foram respondidas, é viável o questionador (no caso eu) enviar o link para que isto seja respondido ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues isso é ótimo. Pois em tais casos, observe que pedimos a você que fizesse uma nova pergunta. Ao você comentar deixando o link dela, ficará mais fácil saber que você "atendeu nosso pedido", pois seremos notificado do seu comentário.

Comment: *O usuário pode estar se expressando naturalmente.* pode até ser como ele se interage e como não temos sensação da expressão corporal não temos certeza de nada. Mas ele continuou sendo *mau educado* e por fim pediu desculpas, não vejo como um atitude boa !!! principalmente para vários aspectos da vida!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ah, talvez sejam comentários que eu não tenha visto. Mas acho que a moderação já tomou/vai tomar conta do assunto. Mesmo comentários deletados podem ser visto por eles.

Comment: Sim, tudo bem @WallaceMaxters ...