# Remover ou Responder Pergunta contendo como resposta o próprio Exemplo da Questão?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade, perguntas-sem-resposta

o que devo fazer com uma nova publicação feita por mim, no qual não conseguia enxergar dentro do meu próprio exemplo a resposta.

E ao realizar novos testes alternativos .. toda minha dúvida foi solucionada apenas colocando mais uma `string` dentro do meu exemplo [Como faço um sistema de busca por data?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187432/como-fa%C3%A7o-um-sistema-de-busca-por-data)

Torna-se um pouco vergonhoso pra mim não ter visto antes a mudança que iria solucionar o problema todo que estava a complicar, e acabo de achar um detalhe bobo, pelo qual derruba toda minha questão em si.

**Então quero saber dos caros colegas, devo pedir pra remover ou colocar o meu código-fonte da Pergunta com a nova edição como Resposta?**

Referências:

[O que fazer quando criador da pergunta resolveu sua dúvida/problema mas não posta como resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2420/o-que-fazer-quando-criador-da-pergunta-resolveu-sua-d%c3%bavida-problema-mas-n%c3%a3o-post)

[Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%c3%b3pria-pergunta)

[Responder o que está na pergunta? e prever o futuro!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5379/responder-o-que-est%c3%a1-na-pergunta-e-prever-o-futuro)

Comment: Eu entendo que se não for um erro de digitação, que geralmente é considerada como fora do escopo, não tem problema responder a si próprio com a solução, por mais que lhe pareça algo simples,

Comment: @diegofm +1 Pelo incentivo. Mas temo receber downVote. rsrs

Comment: Ja aconteceu comigo de eu levar horas para achar um erro, postar uma pergunta e ver o erro relendo a pergunta, não digo que você deve fazer o mesmo que fiz, mas eu preferi remover a pergunta :P

Comment: Tenta dar um up nela, sobe ela pra primeira pagina, veja se ganha mais atenção e alguém responda, se não, se você postar sua solução, não acho que tenha problema você responder ela....

Comment: É melhor você a sua responda, pois assim você poderá estar ajudando os outros que estão com o mesmo problema que você a solucionar o problemas deles.

Comment: @Cava Grato pelo seu apoio. :D